# "E: The list of sources could not be read." while trying to update

Tags: software-center, updates

When I try to update, I get this:

```
root@deepit-R405-A-CPD6A2:/var/lib/apt# sudo apt-get update
E: Type '123443215' is not known on line 61 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: Start by posting your `/etc/apt/sources.list` so we can see how damaged it is but if you open that file with a text editor, ie `gedit` with sudo privileges you should be able to comment out the broken line with `#`, save it and re-run `sudo apt-get update`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and fix (at least) line 61 of it. You can edit it by opening a terminal window and doing:

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

You can comment out that line by putting a `#` at the start of the line.

Comment: Solved it! Some unnecessary additions in the list file. This was really stupid, but i'm new to Linux :P. Thanks guys!