# Cannot install Skype

Tags: installation, package-management, skype, voip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“E: The list of sources could not be read.” while trying to update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101955/e-the-list-of-sources-could-not-be-read-while-trying-to-update)
>    [“Malformed line 6” error in my /etc/apt/sources.list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170486/malformed-line-6-error-in-my-etc-apt-sources-list)

Evey time I try to install skype it says :

```
Reading package lists ... ready
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... ready
The package skype-bin: i386 is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
E: Malformed line 60 in source list / etc / apt / sources.list (distribution analysis)
E: The list of sources could not be read
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/q/101955/12864)?

Comment: @TomBrossman sorry don't know, how do I do it?

Comment: Can you please try the [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/102018/12864) there and see if that fixes it? You need to press Ctrl + Alt + T, then type `gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and put a `#` in front of line 60.

Comment: @TomBrossman should I post the sources list?

Comment: You can if you like. Why not try the solution first and see if it works? No need to carry on with editing the question if you have an answer already.

Comment: @TomBrossman but the answer didn't work... here is the sources list  with "#" on the 60th line as you said: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1180409/

Comment: I see the problem, in lines 59 and 60 'archive' is misspelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have spelling mistakes in lines 59 & 60, you should just remove the lines completely.

[image: /etc/sources.list spelling errors]

Then, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: But still didn't work...

Comment: @Erikson What didn't work? If you deleted lines 59 & 60, you can't see that same error about line 60 you had before. If you have a new or similar problem try searching for an answer here, then post a new question if you still have an issue that hasn't been posted already. You can also try [asking in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201) for help.

Comment: @Erikson Also, looking at [all your questions posted recently](http://askubuntu.com/users/86658/erikson?tab=questions) I see a common thread, they all involve typing mistakes in your list of software sources. Since you've only had Ubuntu installed a few days it might be easier to just do a clean reinstall to address these (and any other) mistakes. If not, [Mik's answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/182946/12864) is probably the clearest explanation so far. Remember, every letter (and space) are important, they have to be 100% correct. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try to install from skype.com.
http://www.skype.com/intl/en/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/downloading.ubuntu32

Here is the 32bit .deb package.

Comment: @cOO1os My lapto is an 64bit platform.. will it work?

Comment: http://www.skype.com/intl/en/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/downloading.ubuntu64